# Reminder that pops up even after the set time has passed?

Tags: software-recommendation

Let's say I need to be reminded on August 1 at 10 AM to call Sally.

But I don't turn my computer on until 10:30 AM.

Is there a reminder program that will pop up when I turn on my computer, even though the reminder time (10 AM) has passed?

I have tried: Tomboy with the reminder plug-in, but it does not have this functionality.

Thanks so much for any suggestions you might have.

Answer (score 0):

TkRemind (GUI for the Remind program) almost fits the bill so it's what I'm using for now - if I put my computer into suspend at 9 AM and turn it back on at 10:30 AM it will tell me about the 10 AM reminder. It doesn't work if my computer was off, but you CAN tell it to give you all of the day's reminders when you start the program, which means I'm not missing anything anymore. More info on Remind: [Linux Journal article](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3529)